# How to specify fields to use of form in view?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have model:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    field_1 = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
    field_2 = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
    field_3 = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
    field_4 = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
    field_5 = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
```

and I must generate three forms:

```
class Form1(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = ['field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3']


class Form2(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = ['field_1', 'field_2', 'field_4']


class Form3(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = ['field_1', 'field_2', 'field_5']
```

How convert it into one form and influence the "fields" in view? I show all this forms in one template.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using class based views? I would suggest using CreateView/UpdateView to do this. You won't need to create a form at all since the class handles that, and you can just specify the fields attribute on the view for whichever fields you want for that particular view. The django doc has a really good example of this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#model-forms

```
class AuthorUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Author
    fields = ['name']
```

So for your example it could be:

```
class View1(CreateView):
   model= ModelA
   fields = ['field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3']

class View2(CreateView):
   model= ModelA
   fields = ['field_1', 'field_2', 'field_4']

class View3(CreateView):
   model= ModelA
   fields = ['field_1', 'field_2', 'field_5']
```